# Unit Conversion with Lists and Dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary, ipython, list-comprehension

I'm working on a project which requires me to make a function unit_convertor('filename', D), which converts all length, filesize, and time units written in a text file to target units. D is a dictionary that specifies to which units lengths, filesizes, and times are to be converted. So if we wanted to convert length to cm, D would be {'length':'cm'}

For example, if test.txt contained *'The computer had 8 GB of RAM, and was able to complete the operation in 120 sec.'*, and D was {'filesize':'KB', 'time':'min'}, the output would be *'The computer had 8000 KB of RAM, and was able to complete the operation in 2 min.'*

So far, I have managed to convert the text to a list, with each word a string, and each number a float. What I am struggling with is how to multiply the number by the required factor in order for it to match up with the unit, and how to replace the unit using the dictionary above. I have read around the use of dictionaries, and am still very lost with how to create this function.

This is the code I have so far, I have focused more on getting the code to work with a defined text file to make sure it works before making the function:

```
f = open('example_text.txt')
fstring = f.read()
fstring = fstring.replace('\n',"")
lista = fstring.split()

listb = []
for i in lista:
    try:
        listb.append(float(i))
    except ValueError:
        listb.append(i)
```

I am very new to Python and am really struggling with this!

I have been told that it would be easiest to write 3 functions, one for converting time, one for length, and one for filesize, and call these within the main function. If I could figure out how to convert one type of unit, I could figure out the other 2 easily.

Answer (score 1):

That's not an easy task for a beginner. You have a few steps:

1. split the text into words
2. locate the units and the associated values
3. convert the source units-values to target units-values
4. replace the units-values in the words and reassemble the text.

Here's a proof of concept (I used a lot of list comprehension for brevty, but you should expand them into functions). Let's try with your example:

```
>>> sentence = "The computer had 8 GB of RAM, and was able to complete the operation in 120 sec."
```

## Split the text into words

First, you need to parse the sentence into chunks. Use a regex. The pattern `\W` matches everything that is not a word. With parentheses, you keep the delimiters:

```
>>> import re
>>> chunks = re.split("(\W)", sentence)
>>> chunks
['The', ' ', 'computer', ' ', 'had', ' ', .... , '120', ' ', 'sec', '.', '']
```

It's easy to reassemble the text:

```
>>> "".join(chunks)
'The computer had 8 GB of RAM, and was able to complete the operation in 120 sec.'
```

## Locate the units and the associated values

You're not interested in spaces. Get the indices with `enumerate` and remove the spaces (`c.strip()` is `False`):

```
>>> enumerated_chunks = [(i, c) for i, c in enumerate(chunks) if c.strip()]
>>> enumerated_chunks
[(0, 'The'), (2, 'computer'), (4, 'had'), (6, '8'), (8, 'GB'), (10, 'of'), (12, 'RAM'), (13, ','), (16, 'and'), (18, 'was'), (20, 'able'), (22, 'to'), (24, 'complete'), (26, 'the'), (28, 'operation'), (30, 'in'), (32, '120'), (34, 'sec'), (35, '.')]
```

Let's say you have two families of units: sizes and times.

```
>>> source_units = ('gb', 'sec') # ordered : sizes then times
```

If we `zip` the `enumerated_chunks` list woth itself, we have the couple of consecutive chunks:

```
>>> list(zip(enumerated_chunks, enumerated_chunks[1:]))
[((0, 'The'), (2, 'computer')), ((2, 'computer'), (4, 'had')), ..., ((34, 'sec'), (35, '.'))]
```

Assuming that you have always the value followed by the unit (this is a strong assumption), you will look for units in the sentence, and store the value preceeding the unit:

```
>>> value_units = []
>>> for (i, v), (j, u) in zip(enumerated_chunks, enumerated_chunks[1:]):
...     u = u.casefold() # compare lowercase strings
...     if u in source_units and v.isdigit(): # a unit predeeded by an integer
...         value_units.append(((i, float(v)), (j, u), source_units.index(u))) # store the index of the family
>>> value_units
[((6, 8.0), (8, 'gb'), 0), ((32, 120.0), (34, 'sec'), 1)]
```

## Convert the source units-values to target units-values

The conversion table between units is a matrix, but we can imagine we have a reference unit of value 1 and other are just multiples:

```
>>> sizes = {'gb':10**9, 'mb':10**6, 'kb':10**3, 'b':1}
>>> times = {'hour':3600, 'min':60, 'sec':1}
>>> families = (sizes, times) # same order as source_units
```

Let the target units:

```
>>> target_units = ('mb', 'min') # ordered as families
```

We get target units and want to find the families:

```
>>> value_units_and_more = [((i, v), (j, u), target_units[f], families[f]) for (i, v), (j, u), f in value_units]
>>> value_units_and_more # you should use classes instead of tuples of tuples
[((6, 8.0), (8, 'gb'), 'mb', {'gb': 1000000000, 'mb': 1000000, 'kb': 1000, 'b': 1}), ((32, 120.0), (34, 'sec'), 'min', {'hour': 3600, 'min': 60, 'sec': 1})]
>>> indexed_chunks = [((i, v*vals[su]/vals[tu]), (j, tu)) for (i, v), (j, su), tu, vals in value_units_and_more]
>>> indexed_chunks
[((6, 8000.0), (8, 'mb')), ((32, 2.0), (34, 'min'))]
```

## Replace the units-values in the words and reassemble the text

We flatten the tuples and create a dictionary `index -> new word`:

```
>>> new_chunk_by_index = dict(t for ts in indexed_chunks for t in ts)
>>> new_chunk_by_index
{6: 8000.0, 8: 'mb', 32: 2.0, 34: 'min'}
```

And replace the words:

```
>>> "".join(str(new_chunk_by_index.get(i, chunk)) for i, chunk in enumerate(chunks))
'The computer had 8000.0 mb of RAM, and was able to complete the operation in 2.0 min.'
```

(`d.get(i, chunk)` takes the value mapped to `i` in the dict `new_chunk_by_index`, or leaves `chunks` if there is no value.)

Warning: This is just a proof of concept. There are certainly a lot of edge case: think of plural, float values, cases where unit preceed the value...

---

You have another (and maybe easier) solution: use [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to locate a number followed by a unit, `repl` being a function that does the conversion as above.